# rails server shows an error after creating a gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, gemset

I have installed rvm. After creation of a gemset for a new project, when i give the command `rails server`, it shows this error `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem railties (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in`activate`

So  i found a solution that i need to give the command `gem install rails` to install rails. 
Is it necessary to install rails for every new project? I am confused. Please guide me the real thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemsets are separating environments, you need to install gems for every new gemset, if you will always use the same version of rails you can install gems in `global` gemset:

```
rvm @global do gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "bundle install" on your project root? This could fix that error.